# What is an alternative to simulate a "create view" function in neo4j?

Tags: java, sql, neo4j, cypher, create-view

I have a data set of about 0.5 million embedded to a Java application. Im trying to accomplish something like:

1 - Perform a friends-of-friends like cypher query `(“MATCH (n)-[r:rel*3]->(m) return n,r,m”)`
2 - Perform queries on these subsets

The idea is like the create view in SQL. I read this post on the google group about that looks like my concern.

`https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/sql$20view/neo4j/kFa8_ZJYzEM/0KuulGphrTYJ`

Do you think that labeling the nodes,as some kind of flag, on the first query is the best option? In terms of performance, when I recall the "flag" nodes, even if it is fast, I re-run the query on the entire data set, so I guess it is a bit consuming.
Is there any other neo4j function that I am forgetting? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Labeling the nodes with some kind of a flag doesn't seem like a very good option.  You'll still have to query for the nodes that have the special property in which case why not just re-issue the original query that created the view?

Which by the way should stay an option -- just re-issuing the query as needed.   Off-hand, you have several other options:

1. In the java layer implement a [traversal](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) that encapsulates/returns what the view should be, and then work with that.
2. Rather than adding a property, you could add a label to the nodes [via a create statement](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create.html#create-create-node-and-add-labels) (you'll still have to query for nodes that have your "view" label to do anything with your "view")
3. Create a special index node.   Label it "VIEW".  Then create relationships from that index node to all nodes that are in the view  (e.g. VIEWNODE-[r:contains]->someObjectInView).   By grabbing that index node handle and traversing only the [r:contains], you can "recompute" the view quickly.

Ultimately what you pick depends on the sort of query you want to do on the "views".